# Continuous time-domain electrical signal that only has a finite number of possible values

Tags: continuous-signals

I have recently started learning DSP and the book that I am reading challenges the readers to find a:

> continuous time-domain electrical signal that only has a finite number
>   of amplitude values

I obviously could not think of an example and hence I am here.

Please suggest an example of continuous electrical signal that takes only finite number of discrete values ?

Comment: _Continuous_ in this context does not mean _continuous function of time_ but rather a function _defined_ for _all time_ or for all $t$ in a _continuum_ meaning _intervals_ such as $[0,T]$ or $(0,T)$ or $(0,\infty)$ (or unions of intervals) as opposed to _discrete-time_ signals that are defined only for specific instants of time, e.g. $nT$ for all $n \geq 0$, and whose values are not specified for any other times, e.g. $x(0.5T)$ is unknown but $x(0)$ and $x(T)$ (often denoted as $x[0]$ and $x[T]$) are known, or can be talked about in the discussion on hand.

Comment: like a square wave?

Comment: @endolith Yes, like a square wave. If _continuous_ were to have the usual meaning "continuous function of $t$", then the _only_ functions that take on a finite number of values are the _constant_ functions -- DC as jan's answer calls them -- which take on only one value. Note that MattL's _piecewise constant_ signal (a specific example of which is your square wave) is _not_ a continuous function of time. Indeed, "continuous time-domain signal" would be better expressed as "continuous-time signal" which is what is meant. Else, it is a trick question to which Matt L's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard example would be a piecewise constant signal (with quantized amplitudes), e.g. generated by an ideal [sample-and-hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_and_hold) circuit (check the figure in the link). Or the output of an ideal DAC (before the reconstruction filter), see the figure in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D/A_converter).

Comment: @QuakiGabbar I added one more (idealized) example (DAC) to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a DC signal for sure.

Other than that, there is probably more context from the book required (especially about the assumptions).

Comment: There is nothing else in the question. Please refer to the original question (Q 1.2) at: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1650107&seqNum=10  just in case you think I have missed something.

Answer (score 2):

The problem asks to think of a

> continuous time-domain electrical signal that only has a finite number of amplitude values

The word 'electrical' makes me think of real physical signals which we can watch on oscilloscopes' screens. Those ones never have fixed amplitude values. One of the causes for example is power supply noise. This is why I think DAC output, DC signal or even Ground (0V) can't be the answer.

In addition if we think about a DAC output signal, the signal needs to change its value instantly. In no time the output must to switch from V1 volts to V2 volts without taking any values between V1 and V2. It would require infinite electrical current through the DAC circuit which unfortunately is not possible.

In my opinion the limitation 'has a finite number of amplitude values' automatically makes the signals mathematical abstractions in someone's head. They can't be real world signals.